# Ionic 2 Provider Can't Resolve all parameters

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm getting an error which I have no idea what is the problem. My app has a login page and a blocks page. If I enable the login page as Root in my app.component.ts and after this I click on login, I get redirected to my blocks page. However, if I set my BlocksPage as root, I get an error in one of my providers:  "Can't resolve all parameters for Auth (Http, ?, AlertController, LoadingController"

I have three providers: CustomHttp, BlocosData and Auth. The Auth and BlocosData providers use CustomHttp provider to make http requests on my API. However, my BlocosPage doesn't use Auth Provider and, even so, the error is in Auth Provider. Here is the gist to all my files:
https://gist.github.com/mbackermann/77d436006b236bb7d57437df1084c904

Comment: Can you add bloco.ts to the gist, please.

Comment: Done @VictorGodoy! Thanks for helping me

Comment: First try to declare all your providers only at the **@NgModule** level. So delete all the providers in the **@Component**

Comment: Still facing the same issue. I removed all the providers in the @Component, but I still need to import, right? I update my gist and also included registration.ts page.

Comment: I thought BlocoPage was bloco.ts wheres it's that file?

Comment: BlocoPage is bloco.ts It was wrong in my gist. I corrected it

Comment: but bloco.ts it's Blocos not BlocoPage

Comment: I already corrected it in my gist

Comment: Have you discovered any thing?